# Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source:

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have deployed my function with no problems to my dev project.

When I try to deploy to production I get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
```

I have over 100 cloud functions and have not encountered this error before in the past.
I have not updated any of the firebase packages the only thing that I am aware of that has changed is the code. Mostly added new functions. These have all be deployed to dev with no problem.

Any ideas what may be causing this error?

```
"firebase-admin": "^9.12.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.24.1",
"firebase-tools": "^9.22.0",
```

End of additional logs from using --debug:

```
[2023-07-16T23:50:40.522Z] Building nodejs source
[2023-07-16T23:50:40.526Z] Could not find functions.yaml. Must use http discovery
[2023-07-16T23:50:40.547Z] Found firebase-functions binary at 'R:\hivepass\HivePassCloud\functions\node_modules\.bin\firebase-functions'
[2023-07-16T23:50:40.790Z] Serving at port 8848

[2023-07-16T23:50:41.173Z] Got response from /__/functions.yaml Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
[2023-07-16T23:50:41.177Z] Failed to parse functions.yaml incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is missed; or followed by a non-tabulated empty line at line 1, column 60:
     ...  from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of unde ...
                                         ^ {"name":"YAMLException","reason":"incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is missed; or followed by a non-tabulated empty line","mark":{"name":null,"buffer":"Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')\n\u0000","position":59,"line":0,"column":59},"message":"incomplete explicit mapping pair; a key node is missed; or followed by a non-tabulated empty line at line 1, column 60:\n     ...  from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of unde ... \n
                             ^"}
[2023-07-16T23:50:41.185Z] {"severity":"INFO","message":"shutdown requested via /__/quitquitquit"}


Error: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had not update the config in the production environment, this was set in dev.

I figured it had to be something different in the environments so it did not take too long to find.

firebase functions:config:set value="myvalue"